# Add compile flags per default clang++

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, clang++, compiler-flags

I want to add some flags per default, so as not to type them at each compilation.

is there any way to add compile flags per default ?

Like optimisation flags or whatever. I found a solution with alias, but i dont know if its a good way, if u have better ideas !

Comment: A makefile perhaps?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No i really want a solution without makefiles, in shell, something per default like -std=c++... you got me ?

Comment: Put your flags into a environment variable, and reference it.

Comment: As soon as you get more complicated multi-file projects, shell commands and scripts will be too much work. I'd recommend you learn the build-tools available in your environment, or perhaps even learn how to use an IDE (which will help with much more than just building your projects correctly).

Comment: I'm afraid there are no magic buttons to push that will make things happen the way everyone likes them to happen. C++ is just too complicated. The proper and the simplest way to implement this is with a Makefile.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Makefile` with the following contents:

```
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++17 -O2
```

Now you can type `make foo` to compile `foo.cpp` with the defaults flags in your Makefile.